# Elisp: reading a constant

Tags: elisp

When reading the constant `:hi`,
I get the error:

> test: Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, :hi

```
(defun test ()
   :hi "greet"
   (insert :hi)
 )

(test)
```

What does it mean? Why is "greet" not the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your Error Message

`insert` operates on `string`s or `character`s, but you gave it a `symbol` (`:hi`). Put your cursor on `insert` and hit <kbd>C-h f RET</kbd> (or do <kbd>C-h f insert RET</kbd> anywhere) and you will get the description of the function `insert` in buffer `*Help*`.

## Your Problem

My ESP tells me that you think that `:hi "greet"` in the beginning of your code should bind variable `:hi` to value `"greet"` and then `(insert :hi)` should call `insert` on the value of `:hi` that should be `"greet"`.

This is not the case.

1. `:hi "greet"` has no effect whatsoever.
2. `:hi` is a keyword, it is always a constant that evaluates to itself and cannot be bound.
3. To bind a local variable, use [`let`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/let.html), try <kbd>C-h f let RET</kbd>.

Thus your code should be

```lisp
(def test()
  "my function to insert a greeting"
  (let ((hi "greet"))
    (insert hi)))
```

## Remedy

I urge you to read ["An Introduction to Programming in Emacs
Lisp"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html),
you will not regret it.
The best way to do it is in Emacs: <kbd>C-h i m intro TAB RET</kbd>.

Comment: If it is that way, why are functions written like
(defun test
:someConstant "variable" [...] ?

Comment: This is ***NOT*** how `defun` works! Please do read the intro to Emacs Lisp or at least the doc for `defun`.

Comment: ups, sorry i mixed this up with a function call